# Del variable inside a Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, del

I am very new to python and programming. I am learning about loops right now, and tried the following code to see what would happen. What I would like to know is why the following code does not crash or keep repeating "Robert".

Thank you.

```
name = ["Robert", "Mike", "Garry", "Alex"]
for y in name:
    print(y)
    del y

print("END")
```

Comment: So you are asking why it works?

Comment: The `for` loop iterates over the values in the `name` variable. The first time it sets the variable `y` to "Robert." The next time it sets `y` to "Mike." The next time it sets `y` to "Garry." etc...

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration of the for loop creates a "new" `y`.  By deleting this `y` each time, you are simply deleting the `y` that belongs to that iteration.  It is "recreated" again at the start of the next iteration.

The del won't change the result of this code at all.

Comment: Python doesn't have block scope.

Comment: How would the computer/program remember that it already went through previous items if it is resetting the y variable in each round of the loop? Is there some hidden variable within python that is keeping track or something?

Comment: Yes. It's either using an internal index, or it is using the iterator protocol. In this case it's a list so it's using an index.

Answer (score 0):

The code works because after you delete the name `y`, you create it again in the next iteration of the loop.

If you try to print `y` after the loop, you'll see that it won't work with the `del` statement in.